# PHP Syntax Checking in Notepad++

Tags: ide, editor, notepad++, syntax-checking

is there a plugin for notepad++ that allows for files to be run through a compiler for simple syntax checking? such as to catch missing ; or or non-matching brace counts, etc.?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not tested myself, but you should be able to do this with the Run Command (F5) and a windows binary of PHP.

The command you most likely would want is as follows:

`cmd /K c:\path\to\php.exe -l $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. Use Netbeans PHP. It's great. I haven't looked back since I switched to it

Comment: Netbeans is nice, and I use it for java, but it takes forever to startup, and with php I usually edit multiple files sid-by-side in in npp.

Comment: Well if you get Netbeans PHP (not the full Netbeans including the PHP package) it's a lot faster but will never be as fast as n++. But what do you expect? You can't have live compiling/error reporting without compromising some speed/fluency. I think it's worth it

Comment: Interesting. I find Netbeans with PHP package blazing fast for file editing. Working with projects depending on size slows down things a bit. It has some cool code selecting features notepad++ does not have like ctrl+. on a string will start selecting section of code outward - very useful